# Python encoding in Windows command line: Chcp 932 doesn't work?

Tags: python, windows, csv, unicode, encoding

I've looked at other answers, and have done what they recommended:

```
1. Changed system locale to Japanese
2. Chcp 932 (Japanese)
3. Python file saved as UTF-8
4. All inputs are subject to the unicode(input, 'utf-8') function as seen below.
```

NOTE: I've also tried using chcp 65001, but this doesn't work either.

I'm trying to read a csv file in Japanese, but the following error keeps coming up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
...
UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp932' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence
```

My code and sample file contents:

```
    def setFood(self):
        reader = self.unicode_csv_reader(open("food.csv"))
        aDict = {}
        for field1, field2 in reader:
            if field2 not in aDict.keys():
                aDict[field2] = [field1]
            else: 
                aDict[field2] += [field1]
        return aDict

    def unicode_csv_reader(self, utf8_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
        reader = csv.reader(utf8_data, dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
        for row in reader:
            yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]

    def recFood(self, inp):
        print inp
        for key in self.foodDict.keys():
            for value in self.foodDict[key]:
                print(key)
                print(value)
```

Sample csv

```
ヤクルト,飲み物
カキフライ,洋食
エビフライ,洋食
豚カツ,洋食
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The example at the bottom of the Python 2.7 csv module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#examples) is what you want, but use `utf-8-sig` for the encoding.  The `\ufeff` is a byte order mark (BOM) character and that encoding will handle it correctly if present.

You *will* need to have the Japanese system locale to print in the Windows console.  Better, switch to Python 3.6 which will print in the console using Unicode APIs...all you need is a font that supports Japanese.  The `csv` module in Python 3 is Unicode-aware as well and works much better.

```
import csv, codecs

class UTF8Recoder:
    """
    Iterator that reads an encoded stream and reencodes the input to UTF-8
    """
    def __init__(self, f, encoding):
        self.reader = codecs.getreader(encoding)(f)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        return self.reader.next().encode("utf-8")

class UnicodeReader:
    """
    A CSV reader which will iterate over lines in the CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8-sig", **kwds):
        f = UTF8Recoder(f, encoding)
        self.reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=dialect, **kwds)

    def next(self):
        row = self.reader.next()
        return [unicode(s, "utf-8") for s in row]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

with open('food.csv','rb') as f:
    r = UnicodeReader(f)
    for key,value in r:
        print key,value
```

> ```
> ヤクルト 飲み物
> カキフライ 洋食
> エビフライ 洋食
> 豚カツ 洋食
> ```